# Dynamic nested tabs using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am a biginner to php and mysql coding. I am trying to create nested tabs dynamically.

I have created nested tabs using html, css, js. I mentioned the code below for the same. My question is how to achieve the same result dynamically using php and mysql.

Can anyone please tell me the php code for nested tabs.

Thanks in advance!!

```js
$(".stock li:first").addClass("current");
$(".tab-inhalt:first").fadeIn();
$(".tab-content:first").fadeIn();

$(".plaene a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass("current");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
  var tab = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
  $("li:first a",tab).click();
});

$(".reiter a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass("current");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
  var tab = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".tab-inhalt").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
  .tab-content,
.tab-inhalt {
  display: none;
}
.stock li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.stock a {
  color: #0094cd;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.stock li.current a {
  color: #4c565c;
}
.plaene a.current {
  color: #4c565c;
}
.tab-alles {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.tab-oben li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
}
.tab-oben a {
  color: #0094cd;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="stock">
  <ul class="plaene">
    <li class="current"><a href="#objecttabs1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#objecttabs2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#objecttabs3">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- End: .stock -->

<div class="tab-alles">
  <div class="tab-oben">
    <div id="objecttabs1" class="tab-content">
      <ul class="reiter">
        <li class="current"><a href="#innertab1">InnerTab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#innertab2">InnerTab2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="objecttabs2" class="tab-content">
      <ul class="reiter">
        <li class=""><a href="#innertab3">InnerTab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#innertab4">InnerTab2</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="objecttabs3" class="tab-content">
      <ul class="reiter">
        <li><a href="#innertab5">InnerTab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#innertab6">InnerTab2</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>

    
  </div> <!-- End: .tab-oben -->
  
  <div class="tab-inhalt-all">
    <div id="innertab1" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="innertab2" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="innertab3" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="innertab4" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="innertab5" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content5</div>
    </div>
    <div id="innertab6" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content6</div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End: .tab-inhalt-all -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment. So the only way to help you out is like this.

If you want to "generate" these tabs automatically using PHP (and MySQL?) you could do the following: (if you need help on the MySQL part as well, drop a comment and I'll edit this)

here's a we-transfer link you can download an example database from for your tabs:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/09eedb2dd16806841befe2b7701f3fab20210325114020/d426c8

The PHP, HTML, and JS:

```
  <?php
  $servername = "";//location of the database
  $username = "";//username to access
  $password= "";//password to access
  $dbname = "Tabs";//database you want to access

  //establish connection:
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  //get the data from the db
  $output = sqlStringGetAsArray($conn, "SELECT * FROM Tabs");//This is the "Tabs" table in the "Tabs" database

  function sqlStringGetAsArray($conn, $sql=""){
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($conn->error){
        return false;
    }
    $array = [];
    $headers=$result->fetch_fields();
    $top = [];
    foreach ($headers as $header){
        $name = $header->name;
        array_push($top, $name);
    }
    array_push($array,$top);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        array_push($array, $row);
    }

    return $array;
  }

  //set the output to the format we need to display:
  $tabContents = [];
  $first = true;
  foreach($output as $val){
    if($first){
      $first = false;
    }else{
      if(!isset($tabContents[$val[1]])){
        $tabContents[$val[1]] = [];
      }
      array_push($tabContents[$val[1]], [$val[2], $val[3]]);
    }
  }
  ?>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='./tabs.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
      <div id='container'>
        <div class='Tabs'>
          <?php
            $i1 = 0;
            foreach($tabContents as $key=>$value){
              if($i1==0){
                echo"<div id='Tab".$i1."' class='level1 active' onclick='updateTabs(this)'>".$key."</div>";
              }else{
                echo"<div id='Tab".$i1."' class='level1' onclick='updateTabs(this)'>".$key."</div>";
              }
              $i1++;
            }
          ?>
        </div>
        <div class='innerTabs'>
          <?php
            $i1 = 0;
            foreach($tabContents as $key=>$value){
              $i2 = 0;
              if($i1 == 0){
                echo("<div id='Tab".$i1."' class='parent visible'>");
                foreach($value as $i){
                  if($i2 == 0){
                    echo"<div id='innerTab".$i2."' class='level2 active' onclick='updateInnerTabs(this)'>".$i[0]."</div>";
                  }else{
                    echo"<div id='innerTab".$i2."' class='level2' onclick='updateInnerTabs(this)'>".$i[0]."</div>";
                  }
                  $i2++;
                }
                $i1++;
              }else{
                echo("<div id='Tab".$i1."' class='parent'>");
                foreach($value as $i){
                  if($i2 == 0){
                    echo"<div id='innerTab".$i2."' class='level2 active' onclick='updateInnerTabs(this)'>".$i[0]."</div>";
                  }else{
                    echo"<div id='innerTab".$i2."' class='level2' onclick='updateInnerTabs(this)'>".$i[0]."</div>";
                  }
                  $i2++;
                }
                $i1++;
                }
              echo("</div>");
            }
          ?>
        </div>
        <div class='contents'>
          <?php
            $i1 = 0;
            foreach($tabContents as $key=>$value){
              $i2 = 0;
              foreach($value as $i){
                if($i1 == 0 && $i2 == 0){
                  echo"<div id='Tab".$i1."_innerTab".$i2."_content' class='level3 visible'>".$i[1]."</div>";
                }else{
                  echo"<div id='Tab".$i1."_innerTab".$i2."_content' class='level3'>".$i[1]."</div>";
                }
                $i2++;
              }
              $i1++;
            }
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
        function updateTabs(el) {
          visibility(el, '.innerTabs');
          $('.innerTabs').children('#' + $(el).attr('id')).addClass('visible');
          updateInnerTabs($('.innerTabs').children('#' + $(el).attr('id')).children().first());
        }
        function updateInnerTabs(el) {
          visibility(el, '.contents');
          var tab = $(el).parent().attr('id') + '_';;
          var innerTab = $(el).attr('id') + '_content';
          $('#' + tab + innerTab).addClass('visible');
        }
        function visibility(el, aClass) {
          $(el).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
          $(el).addClass('active');
          $(aClass).children('.visible').removeClass('visible');
        }
      </script>
      (This bit is at the bottom of the file:)
      <pre>
        <?php
          print_r($tabContents);
        ?>
      </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the CSS:

```
.Tabs{
    background-color: #222;
}

.level1{
    padding: 16px;
    color: #eee;
    background-color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level1.active{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level1:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.innerTabs{
    background-color: #444;
    color: #eee;
}

.parent:not(.visible){
    display: none;
}

.level2{
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level2.active{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #65bd68;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level2:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
}

.contents{
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 16px;
}

.contents div:not(.visible){
    display: none;
}
```

Although this code is not very elegant, it gets the job done, and you can easily get Data from your Database and put it into `$tabContents`.

One way you could organize your table would be like so:
[image]

Bear in mind that the "Tab" value has to be the same for some if you want multiple "innerTabs" for a "tab". This example will have 1 "Tab" with 2 "innerTabs"

Comment: Thank u so much for the code.. If u could help me with mysql part also that would be great..

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for please consider accepting the answer =) ty!

Comment: Thank u so much for the code.. Its working :-)